golang ffprobe-ffmpeg command execution error
I want to get duration of hls. But when I run it gives me error:
exit status 1
Here's my Go code
func (i *ImageGenerationService) GenerateImages(movieID int) (models.FileResponse, error) {
    if _, err := exec.LookPath("ffprobe"); err != nil {
        return models.FileResponse{}, errors.New("video.Init: ffprobe was not found in your PATH ")
    }

    files, err := i.GetVideoFiles(movieID)
    if err != nil {
        i.logger.Warn("failed to get files", zap.Error(err))
        return models.FileResponse{}, err
    }

    var ii int
    var file *models.ProcessedFiles

    for ii, file = range files {
        if file.Quality == "1080p" {
            break
        }
    }
    _, err = os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        i.logger.Warn("failed to get current directory", zap.Error(err))
        return models.FileResponse{}, err
    }


    args := utils.GetDurationScript(files[ii].Filename)

    cmd := exec.Command("ffprobe", args...)
    cmd.Stderr, cmd.Stdout = os.Stderr, os.Stdout
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return models.FileResponse{}, err
    }

    return models.FileResponse{}, nil
}

func GetDurationScript(hls string) []string {
    return []string{
        "-v",
        "quiet",
        "-show_entries",
        "format=duration",
        "-print_format",
        "json",
        "-headers",
        `"Authorization: YOUR_TOKEN"`,
        hls,
    }
}

I'm using OS X, go1.22.
My HLS file looks like this: https://example.com/999/1080/41509578-e299-4594-a506-cf1ff9864a1b.m3u8
Correct my code if I'm wrong or give me some suggestions of how to fix this!!!

I found my error it was while I'm writing header:
func GetDurationScript(hls string) []string {
    return []string{
        "-v",
        "quiet",
        "-show_entries",
        "format=duration",
        "-print_format",
        "json",
        "-headers",
        `Authorization: YOUR_TOKEN`,
        "-i",
        hls,
    }
}

headers must be without quotes(', '')
